# how fix Property 'usernam' does not exist on type 'Socket<DefaultEventsMap, DefaultEventsMap, DefaultEventsMap>'

Tags: node.js, typescript, socket.io

```ts
socket.on('Username', async (data: any) => {
    clients[data] = socket.id
    socket.usernam = data; //error

    const user = await Users.findByIdAndUpdate(data, {
        $set: { isOnline: true },
    })
})
```

Property 'usernam' does not exist on type 'Socket<DefaultEventsMap, DefaultEventsMap, DefaultEventsMap>'

Comment: Is `usernam` supposed to miss an `e`?

Comment: @kara No
The username must be replaced with the data value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose it is about socket.io. If so, the `socket` variable does not have property `usernam` defined by default. Because we are using TypeScript here, the `socket` is typed, so you can not define and use arbitrary property on that object as you can in JavaScript. If you could, the whole purpose of defining "type of things" will be lost.

But since TypeScript is superset of JavaScript, you can treat any object as arbitrary JavaScript object. So you can "untype" the object `socket` and now it is "classic" JavaScript variable. So:

`(socket as any).usernam = data; // NO ERROR`

But I recommend do not use this approach. You have already `clients` map (one line before error line) so maybe that will suffice?